# ECONNRESET when testing netlify functions and Gatsbyjs 2

Tags: node.js, webpack, gatsby, netlify, http-proxy-middleware

I'm trying to test my lambda functions for Netlify locally using `netlify-lambda`, but can't get the proxy to work with Gatsbyjs. I keep receiving this in the console:

```
[HPM] Rewriting path from "/.netlify/functions/add-subscriber" to "/add-subscriber"
[HPM] GET /.netlify/functions/add-subscriber ~> http://localhost:9000
[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /add-subscriber from localhost:8000 to http://localhost:9000 (ECONNRESET) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
```

This is what I get in the request

> Error occured while trying to proxy to: localhost:8000/add-subscriber

This is what I have in my `gatsby-config.js` file

```
developMiddleware: app => {
  app.use(
    "/.netlify/functions",
    proxy({
      target: "http://localhost:9000",
      pathRewrite: {
        "^/\\.netlify/functions": ""
      },
      logLevel: "debug"
    })
  )
}
```

And this is where I make the request

```
onSubmit(values) {
  fetch('/.netlify/functions/add-subscriber')
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(resp => console.log(resp))
    .catch(e => {
      console.error(e)
    })
}
```

I've tried following several examples, but none of them are working for me. I've also closed any programs that might be using the ports. Testing the URL (http://localhost:9000/add-subscriber) from the browser works fine. Fetching the URL directly also works fine. What could the problem be?

Answer (score 0):

First thing I noticed was that your `pathRewrite` does not match the example in the docs, you're using `"^/\\.netlify/functions"` while the docs use `"/.netlify/functions/"`. Could the fix be that simple?

What happens if you load http://localhost:8000/.netlify/functions/add-subscriber via `curl` or directly in the browser? That should tell you if the configuration is working correctly or not.

Answer (score 0):

Changing to `target: 'http://[::1]:9000',` did the trick for me